# Проблема с RSS датой/временем (Calendar & SimpleDateFormat)

Tags: java, android

Пишу тест для проверки корректного парсинга даты/времени RSS. Но, тест не проходит успешно, как я думаю проблема во временных зонах.

Подскажите в чем ошибка?

**RSSDateHelperTest.java**

```
package com.ragmon.rssreader.helpers;

import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class RSSDateHelperTest {

    @Test
    public void getFromRSSDateString_withLocal() throws ParseException {
        String rssDate = "Tue, 19 Oct 2004 13:38:55 -0200";
        Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("-0200"));
        calendar.set(2004, 10, 19, 13, 38, 55);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();

        assertThat(RSSDateHelper.getFromRSSDateString(rssDate, locale), CoreMatchers.is(date));
    }

}
```

**RSSDateHelper.java**

```
package com.ragmon.rssreader.helpers;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class RSSDateHelper {

    public static Date getFromRSSDateString(String dateString, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", locale);
        return formatter.parse(dateString);
    }

    public static Date getFromRSSDateString(String dateString) throws ParseException {
        return getFromRSSDateString(dateString, Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

Тест не проходит, вот что выдаёт:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <Fri Nov 19 15:38:55 EET 2004>
 but: was <Tue Oct 19 18:38:55 EEST 2004>
Expected :is <Fri Nov 19 15:38:55 EET 2004>

Actual   :<Tue Oct 19 18:38:55 EEST 2004>
```

Comment: Месяца, в данном контексте,  нумеруются с нуля, следовательно, октябрь – девятый месяц.

Comment: @s8am исправил. Но, все равно ошибка. Вот что выводит: `java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <Tue Oct 19 16:38:55 EEST 2004>
     but: was <Tue Oct 19 18:38:55 EEST 2004>
Expected :is <Tue Oct 19 16:38:55 EEST 2004>
     
Actual   :<Tue Oct 19 18:38:55 EEST 2004>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена:

`TimeZone.getTimeZone("-0200")` - не срабатывал.
А также потребовалось проводить утверждение не сравнивая объекты `Date`, а их строковые значения.

```
    @Test
    public void getFromRSSDateString_withLocal() throws ParseException {
        String rssDate = "Tue, 19 Oct 2004 13:38:55 -0200";
        Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-0200"));
        calendar.set(2004, 9, 19, 13, 38, 55);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();

        assertThat(RSSDateHelper.getFromRSSDateString(rssDate, locale).toString(), CoreMatchers.is(date.toString()));
    }
```